# Select last message for each categories

Tags: php, mysql

I created a personal forum with the tables below (only necessary fields) :

```
TABLE category:
id (int)

TABLE subcategory:
id (int)
idCategory (int)

TABLE topic:
id (int)
idUser (int)
idSubcategory (int)

TABLE message:
id (int)
idUser (int)
idTopic (int)
datePub (datetime)
```

So I have messages in topics, in subcategories who are in categories. My objectif is to show in subcategories and categories the last message post by users. For now, I used this mysql request (only to show messages in subcategories):

```
private static function lastMessage() {
    $last_message = Database::getQuery( '
        SELECT DISTINCT max(m.datePub) AS datePub, m.subject, s.id, m.idTopic
        FROM ln_forum_subcategory s 
        LEFT JOIN ln_forum_topic t on s.id = t.idSubcategory
        LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT max(m2.datePub) as datePub, idTopic, max(subject) as subject
        FROM ln_forum_message m2
        LEFT JOIN ln_forum_topic t2 on m2.idTopic = t2.id
        GROUP BY idTopic ORDER BY datePub DESC
        ) m ON m.idTopic = t.id
        GROUP BY s.id
        ORDER BY m.datePub DESC' )->fetchALL( \PDO::FETCH_OBJ );

        return $last_message;
}
```

It works for the date, but not for the ID or the author of the message (can't make a right link to the post).

Does anyone see where the problem is? Thanks !

Comment: ORDER BY m.datePub due to this it only work for date

Comment: "It works for the date, but not for the ID or the author of the message (can't make a right link to the post). Does anyone see where the problem is? Thanks !" yea invalid use off GROUP BY  `SELECT max(m2.datePub) as datePub, idTopic, max(subject) as subject ... GROUP BY idTopic` also in the outer query.. `SELECT DISTINCT max(m.datePub) AS datePub, m.subject, s.id, m.idTopic ... GROUP BY s.id`

Comment: What do you mean by invalid use ? Cause without GROUP BY, I've got all messages without distinction. The problem is with the topic ID. When I want to show it, mysql returns only the first of them. So, if I post a message in the topic n°6, I've got the n°1 no matter where I post the message. The problem is the GROUP BY so?